# Cайт с бесплатным доступом к базам данных

Tags: mysql, sql-server, база-данных

Пишу программу на c# с подключением к базе данных.

Проблема вообщем в том, что у меня нет выделенного адреса в инете, как вариант использовал прогу Hamachi и все пользователи её ставили и подключались к серверу (и естественно он должен быть всегда включен, что не всегда возможно, т.к. он в офисе и оставлять на ночь включенным не хочется).

Подскажите какой-нибудь сайт, где бы можно было бы подключиться, и моей программе использовать базу данных (не важно mysql/mssql или др.), смотрел, вроде в у гугла подобное есть, но не могу это всё сделать.
И как это всё сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Не дело это работать с БД сразу из клиента. Любой более или менее продвинутый пользователь сольет у вас все данные. Лучше сделать прослойку в виде app-сервера и уже из него обращаться к базе, а от клиентов только слушать API-вызовы

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен, очевидно, VDS - виртуальный выделенный сервер. За некоторую ежемесячную плату вам предоставят вычислительные ресурсы и место на жестком диске. А там уже размещайте все, что душе угодно.

[Amazon-овский AWS](http://aws.amazon.com) предоставляет бесплатно на год минимальную конфигурацию. Возможно, вам подойдет.